# Use Perl to Add 2 days to Today

Tags: perl, time

I want to use perl and add two days from today and output this as a unix time. I have found lots of information on how to convert Unix time to readable time but I need the ouput to be a unix time. I found this

```
my $time = time;    # or any other epoch timestamp 
my @months = ("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul",
              "Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");
my ($sec, $min, $hour, $day,$month,$year) = (localtime($time))[0,1,2,3,4,5]; 
# You can use 'gmtime' for GMT/UTC dates instead of 'localtime'
print "Unix time ".$time." converts to ".$months[$month].
      " ".$day.", ".($year+1900);
```

How do I take current time and add 2 days and output as Unix time.

Comment: use DateTime module for that

Comment: You can also use Time::Piece, which is a core module.

Comment: What do you mean by "Unix time"?

Comment: @cdarke http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: Ah, seconds since epoc.  So get current time then add 2 day's worth of seconds (2 * 24 * 60 * 60).

Comment: Yes I need current plus 17280 I just don't know perl well enough to write the script.

Answer (score 16):

Have you considered using the [`DateTime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) package?  It contains a lot of date manipulation and computation routines, including the ability to add dates.

There is an FAQ, with examples, [here](http://datetime.perl.org/wiki/datetime/dashboard) (in particular, see the section on sample calculations and DateTime formats).

Here is a snippet:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime;

my $dt = DateTime->now();
print "Now: " . $dt->datetime() . "\n";
print "Now (epoch): " . $dt->epoch() . "\n";

my $two_days_from_now = $dt->add(days => 2);
print "Two days from now: " . $two_days_from_now->datetime() . "\n";
print "Two days from now (epoch): " . $two_days_from_now->epoch() . "\n";
```

Which produces the following output:

```
Now: 2013-02-23T18:30:58
Now (epoch): 1361644258
Two days from now: 2013-02-25T18:30:58
Two days from now (epoch): 1361817058
```

Comment: @Borodin It is clearer than `my($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst)=localtime(time()+(2*24*60*60));`. It is also fast-enough that I doubt you would notice the speed difference.

Comment: @BradGilbert: What is wanted is *just* the epoch time, so `print time() + 172800` is all that is necessary. Efficiency isn't an issue, but I disagree that this version is clear.

Comment: @Borodin - This version is plenty clear. The only reason it's more 'work' is because it does more than yours - it prints before and after (for demonstration purposes) - if you strip it down to just what is required, it's at most one more call or piece of 'work' than yours. Your answer references a magic number. A built-in one, but one nonetheless.

Comment: @Doug: Oh come on. The shortest this can be is `use Datetime; print Datetime->now->add(days => 2)->epoch;` which IMO is ridiculous when all that is required is `print time() + 2 * 24 * 60 * 60`.

Comment: "Oh come on" indeed - the feeling is mutual.

Comment: @StevenTharp If this worked for you, consider accepting the answer =]

Answer (score 2):

yuu can change the timestamp, which is seconds from epoc

change

```
my $time = time;
```

to

```
my $time = time + 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 ; # 60 seconds 60 minutes 24 hours times 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Now is `time()`. Two days from now is `time() + 2 * 86400`. Today (midnight at the beginning of the current day) is `int(time() / 86400) * 86400`. Two days from today is today plus 2 * 86400. `localtime` in scalar context will print any of them out as a readable date, unless you really want `gmtime` or `strftime` (from the POSIX module).

Answer (score -1):

The `time` function returns the current epoch seconds, and core module `Time::Seconds` provides useful constants for time periods.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Seconds 'ONE_DAY';

print time + ONE_DAY * 2;
```

**output**

```
1361872751
```